# Vue CLI and Bootstrap via Webpack

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, webpack, vue-cli

I'm trying to get bootstrap to work with Vue CLI.
I installed jQuery and Bootstrap like so:

`npm install jquery bootstrap`

and then configured webpack like so:

```
  module.exports = {
    plugins: [
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: "jquery",
        jQuery: "jquery",
        "window.jQuery": "jquery",
        tether: 'tether',
        Tether: 'tether',
        'window.Tether': 'tether',
        Alert: "exports-loader?Alert!bootstrap/js/dist/alert",
        Button: "exports-loader?Button!bootstrap/js/dist/button",
        Carousel: "exports-loader?Carousel!bootstrap/js/dist/carousel",
        Collapse: "exports-loader?Collapse!bootstrap/js/dist/collapse",
        Dropdown: "exports-loader?Dropdown!bootstrap/js/dist/dropdown",
        Modal: "exports-loader?Modal!bootstrap/js/dist/modal",
        Popover: "exports-loader?Popover!bootstrap/js/dist/popover",
        Scrollspy: "exports-loader?Scrollspy!bootstrap/js/dist/scrollspy",
        Tab: "exports-loader?Tab!bootstrap/js/dist/tab",
        Tooltip: "exports-loader?Tooltip!bootstrap/js/dist/tooltip",
        Util: "exports-loader?Util!bootstrap/js/dist/util",
      })
    ],
  }
```

Although no joy. Even with jQuery.

I'm looking for a webpack solution.

Thanks,
Jamie

Comment: What is that not work for you? An error message something like `$ is not defined? Or jQuery is not defined?`

Comment: It's not registering either so I get nothing in the console. I tried using the console `window.$` but it just returns `ƒ $(selector, [startNode]) { [Command Line API] }` with no option to expand the function, so I assume it isn't set at all. I also get  a `Uncaught ReferenceError` when trying to see if any of the bootstrap ones exist.

Comment: @JamieBonnett How did you fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Inside of your `main.js` or `app.js`, whichever one you are using as the main Javascript file, add the following:

```
import 'bootstrap'
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery')
```

Comment: I don't want to add it to the script, do you have a webpack alternative?